# XOR operation on first 256 bytes of an video file

Tags: java, android, file, xor, randomaccessfile

I am trying to implement xor operation on the first 256 bytes of video file which creats an output video file,
I want that output video to stop working, then when the same output video is passed as input, another video file should be created which should behave as original one. Basically I am trying to encrypt and decrypt it.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView text;
    private String workingPath;
    File yourFile;
    File outputFile;
    Button decryptButton;
    byte[] buffer;
    RandomAccessFile raf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      workingPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"";
        outputFile = new File(workingPath, "result4.mp4");
        yourFile = new File(workingPath, "result5.mp4");
      buffer  = new byte[256];

        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(yourFile,"rw");
            raf.read(buffer);
            try {
                Log.d("pos1",raf.getFilePointer()+"");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         //   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(workingPath+"/new.mp4"), buffer);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       byte[] outbyte = xor(buffer);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try {
            raf.seek(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Log.d("pos2",raf.getFilePointer()+"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            raf.write(outbyte);
            byte[] arr = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
            raf.read(arr);

           FileOutputStream fileOuputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            fileOuputStream.write(arr);
            fileOuputStream.close();
            //raf.readFully(o);
            // outputFile = raf;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public static byte[] xor(byte[] a) {
        int key=11;
        byte[] result = new byte[a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    a[i] = (byte)(a[i] ^ key);  // we need to cast it back into a byte because it was converted to an int by XOR
                }

        return result;
    }

}
```

In the above code, the original input video(yourFile) also stops working.I don't know why

Comment: `raf = new RandomAccessFile(yourFile,"rw");` ... `raf.write(outbyte);` That's why ... what do you think this does? If you want to change the copy, only then do not change the original. Simple as that. It would have helped you if you had opened the original file read-only.

Comment: I didnt know yourFile would get affected!!

Comment: But you **write** to it. The method to do so is called _write_ . How can you possibly think it is **not** written to? :D I don't know if you are old enough to know music tapes. But you just listened to the first 5 seconds of your girlfriend's favorite tape, then rewinded the tape and recorded 5 seconds of garbage on the same tape. Your g/f will kill you!

Comment: Ya my bad!! What should I do then? How can I modify first 256 bytes of an output file without affecting the first file?

Comment: Just write to the second file and to that file only. You can put on safety by opening the first file read-only. So you will be prompted an exception on trying to write to it. Basically you open the output, write your garbage to it and then then rest of the original. Throw out rewinding the original stream and you should be fine. BTW: That way you are only destroying it, not encrypting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obviously changing `yourFile` by `raf.write(outbyte);` which will render the video unplayable. This will write to the original file.

What you actually should do instead is write all the bytes of `yourFile` to `outputFile` with the first 256 modified.

Check out this example.

```
import java.io.*;
public class XORTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        RandomAccessFile reader=new RandomAccessFile("a.txt","r");
        RandomAccessFile writer=new RandomAccessFile("b.txt","rw");
        byte[] buffer  = new byte[256];

        reader.read(buffer);
        xor(buffer);
        writer.write(buffer);
        while(true)
        {
            int o = reader.read(buffer);
            if(o < 0)
                break;
            writer.write(buffer);

        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    public static byte[] xor(byte[] a) {
        int key=11;
        byte[] result = new byte[a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    a[i] = (byte)(a[i] ^ key);                     }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly